# Don't scroll on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scroll

i have a `ViewFlipper`, which contains only on `ListView`.The flipper uses SwipeDetection to change Next/Previous-Elements.These implementation works fine, but I have a problem with the scrollig function of the embedded ListView, cause often if I only want to swipe to next/previos view, the ListView ( which implements the swipedetector) scrolls up or down.
Is there an possibility to deativate these scrolling if I only want to swipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own class which extends `ViewFlipper` and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` method for intercepting touch events.

If you always return `true` for this function, your viewflipper will consume all touchEvents

Comment: Thanks, but if i use that, i can't swipe to left or right, cause every event will consume.But i want to consume it only, if i have a swipe detected...